# $(this).data() trims the passed data from a database until a whitespace

Tags: javascript, php

Everything works fine except for the part when I am getting a data with a whitespace. I want to get the whole string of data, not the trimmed one.
In my example, every time I get the "data-title" or "data-type", the data will be cut until the whitespace.
I tried placing a static string of data in "data-title" and it worked perfectly. But when I passed a dynamic one, which is from the database, it is trimmed until the whitespace. $row[1] is perfectly shown on a link but is trimmed when it is passed.

**HTML**

```
<a href='#manage_question_window' class='manage_question' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#manage_question_window' data-id=$row[0] data-title=$row[1] data-type=$row[2]>$row[1]</a>  

<div class="modal fade" id="manage_question_window"> <!-- START management -->
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <!-- HEADER -->
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h2 class="modal-title text-center">Manage Question</h2>
                </div>
                <!-- BODY -->
                <form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="manage_input_question" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Question</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <textarea name="question" class="form-control" id="manage_input_question" placeholder="Question" style="resize:none;"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="manage_input_type" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Answer Type</label>
                            <div class="selectContainer col-sm-10">
                                <select name="type" class="form-control" id="manage_input_type">
                                    <option value="Multiple Choice With Unique Answer">Multiple Choice With Unique Answer</option>
                                    <option value="Multiple Choice With Multiple Answer">Multiple Choice With Multiple Answers</option>
                                    <option value="True or False">True or False</option>
                                    <option value="Identification">Identification</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <!-- BUTTON -->
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="button" id="create_btn" name="create" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Create">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).on("click", ".manage_question", function () {
    var question_id = $(this).data('id');
    var question_title = $(this).data('title');
    var question_type = $(this).data('type');

    $(".modal-body #manage_input_question").val( question_title );
    $(".modal-body #manage_input_type").val( question_type );
});
```

Comment: $(this).data('id').trim() try this

Comment: This works fine for me, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ujyxaadp/). Can you reproduce it?

Comment: It works fine if I place a static string but not when it is dynamic.

Comment: Can you identify the binary value of the whitespace? I'd suggest it's perhaps not a traditional space, but some other rogue character which is causing your script to fail.

Comment: I can't identify its value because I used a mysqli_real_escape_string() function to place the title of the question to the database. But it is a spacebar when I input the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found my mistake here. Instead of

```
data-id=$row[0] data-title=$row[1] data-type=$row[2]
```

It should be enclosed with quotes.

```
data-id=$row[0] data-title='$row[1]' data-type='$row[2]'
```